# How to use HTTP request with a restricted API?

Tags: laravel

In my app there is a code that uses [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client) and the API is accessible only by IPsec VPN like FortiClient VPN with username and password, When I use it locally on my PC it works fine but when I transfer the app to host the request will be timeout. Is there any options I forgot?:

```
$response = Http::get('http://example.com');
```

Comment: It means you need to do site 2 site VPN configuration.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Laravel HTTP Client, use a proxy for your request.

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
   'proxy' => 'http://username:password@proxyhost.com:7000'
])->get('http://example.com');
```